# How to detect if a XControl is visible?

Tags: user-interface, labview

I have a TabPanel and in each Tab is one XControl. This XControl has elements that aggregate data and some that only display the latest. What I would like to do is, disable all elements that do not aggregate data when the XControl is not visible.
The question now is: How do I know what XControl is visible?

I could listen on the tabs on change event and write it into all xcontrols. But is there an easier way?

[image: UI]

Answer (score 3):

You should consider monitoring XControl state within your Fcade.vi
LabVIEW calls the Facade VI with Display State Change event.

You should write the according code that makes the changes you want on the control interface.
Please see attached [image]

Comment: Yes that is something I considered but how do I recognise there that it is not visible anymore?

Comment: You can monitor display change event and get Visible information from Conteiner State Cluster as I understand.

Comment: The container state cluster contains: a boolean for Indicator and Run Mode and a Refnum.

Comment: You use refnum to get the visible state

Comment: How would I do that? But I don't want to actively set it to invisible.

Comment: Read property of the reference.

Comment: Or add a method (or property) to the XControl 'Process Data', this way the client application (that owns the XControls can decide if it's worth to have the additional load.

Comment: Ton Plomp's suggestion is more professional I think. At least I bump up examples people doing that way.